# how to put horizontal recyclerviews inside vertical scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm attempting to put six horizontal recyclerview rows inside a vertical scrollview. What I have is a top recycler row of buttons that let me pick a date followed by the six horizontal recycler views that let me pick items followed by a bottom row of three buttons

The code for my fragment without scroll view is as so:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="db.cbm.com.myapp.MenuPickerFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="@string/pick_menu" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/datePickerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/day_of_week_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/breakfastScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/breakfastList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/snack1ScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/snack1List"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lunchScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/lunchList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/snack2ScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/snack2List"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dinnerLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/dinnerList"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/snack3ScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/snack3List"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/cancel" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/save" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/done" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>

The above works correctly except the images in the six menu picker recycler view rows are too small so I would like to increase their size and put them into a vertical scroll view.

Here's what I think I want but it doesn't work, none of my recyclerviews are present or at least they're not initialized and I don't see any rows. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="db.cbm.com.myApp.MenuPickerFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="@string/pick_menu" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/datePickerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/day_of_week_list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/breakfastScrollView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/breakfastList"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/snack1ScrollView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/snack1List"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lunchScrollView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/lunchList"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/snack2ScrollView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/snack2List"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dinnerLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/dinnerList"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/snack3ScrollView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/snack3List"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/cancel" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/save" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/done" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What kind of problem are you having? What does your code produce, and why do you think your code should work?

Comment: In the xml file, when I wrap the six horizontal recyclerviews in a LinearLayout, appear correctly on screen. When I then wrap the LinearLayout that wraps the six recycler views in a Scrollview it allocates the screen space but none of the recyclerviews inside the wrapping LinearLayout appear. It's as if the space is being allocated but the recyclerviews are not being instanciated.

Comment: I figured it out! I needed to set the android:fillViewport="true" variable for the Scrollview!

Comment: working sample code for similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37619660/1303639